# XRD Peaks in databases

Tags: x-ray-diffraction

I had a look at the JCPDS card of BiOCl and saw that there were very small peaks (such as 0.1 percent relative intensity) that I think wouldn't be observed in XRD pattern, they would just blend in with the noise, so I'd like to know how do they calculate the XRD peaks and know their relative intensities so well (this card referenced a 1935 paper).

Many thanks

Comment: Why do you think they could not measure to 1 part in a 1000?

Comment: Because I thought it would just blend in with the noise. Also I looked at modern papers and they don't label many peaks (because they are too close).

Comment: See, for example, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geiger–Müller_tube for available equipment. There were a bunch of smart people doing good measurements a 100 years ago.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I'm wondering if you were to plot the values from the database (2 theta) vs intensity, and have very sharp peaks, is that what you would expect to get If only n=1 diffraction would occur and there was no noise?

Comment: As a side note, there is no such thing as an "XRD spectrum", it's an oxymoron (although some textbooks use this term improperly) as by definition the radiation is monochromatic. There is an *x-ray spectra* (like [this one of the Cu anode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0mLB.png)) and *x-ray diffraction pattern/diffractogram* (what you are asking about, e.g. $2\theta$ vs intensity). I think someone already pointed this out already in the comments to your previous question which is now deleted by you.

Comment: @andselisk Your point simultaneously was considered in an edit of the original question.

Answer (score 2):

***short answer:*** The record is based on the old record by Bannister 1934 *as first description of this phase* . The fine intensity scaling 1:1000 on the record card is based on a more recent re-investigation.

*recording the data:*

Beside the point detector / Geiger counter technique mentioned in Jon Custer's comment -- still *highly* valuable in powder diffraction analysis -- a common method was to record the diffraction pattern *on a photographic film*.

In the case of powder samples, you used for example Guinier cameras:

[image]

([source](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/a-Principle-of-Guiniers-camera_fig2_332306411))

with a stripe of a film placed in the inner of the housing.  After the experiment, the film was developed; and the more diffraction intensity, the darker the band on the developed film.  The following image depicts a simultaneous analysis of four samples:

[image]

([source](http://pd.chem.ucl.ac.uk/pdnn/inst1/optics2.htm)).

In case of single crystals, *one* method was to place the *oriented* sample in front of a film, for example with a Buerger precession camera

[image]

([source](http://oldwww.iucr.org/iucr-top/comm/cteach/pamphlets/2/node12.html))

to yield clichés like

[image]

([source](https://www.xtal.iqfr.csic.es/Cristalografia/parte_06_2-en.html))

where the *location* of the spots provides information about symmetry distance relationships of the lattice.  (Relative intensity of the spots equally has a meaning, but beyond the scope of this question here.)

In both cases, the intensity of the signals were attributed by eye (e.g., strong, medium, weak), or later by [densitometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Densitometry) and [densitometers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Densitometer) in numbers. While these film methods *today* are superseeded in convenience by positional detectors and CCD arrays (no wet chemistry to develop the films, quick numeric read-out), you still find these noted in volume C of the International Tables of Crystallography, section 7.1 «Detectors for X-rays».

[image]

([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=60FoFEGyShIC&pg=PA619&lpg=PA619&dq=densitometer%20crystallography&source=bl&ots=u29jIqE-fr&sig=ACfU3U0H6DbdkrCZx8Ra_aqbVrPv7GTsVQ&hl=de&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false))

---

*your phase:*

You find the first entry about $\ce{BiOCl}$ as entry [#1011175](http://www.crystallography.net/cod/1011175.html) published 1934 in *Nature*, and [#9011782](http://www.crystallography.net/cod/9011782.html) published 1935 in *Mineralogical Magazine* by the same author as indexed by the [COD](http://www.crystallography.net/cod/index.php) with their `.cif` files. You may use these to predict how a powder diffraction pattern of this phase should look like:

[image]

And indeed, there are some signals *expected* to be much weaker, than others, e.g., reflection $(103)$ (blue rectangle) would be weak and maybe not spot.

Interestingly, the [AMS database](http://rruff.geo.arizona.edu/AMS/minerals/Bismoclite) equally offers access to the Bismoclite data, including a copy of Bannister's publication in *Mineralogical Magazine*, too ([here](http://rruff.geo.arizona.edu/doclib/mm/vol24/MM24_49.pdf)).  And table 2 (*loc. cit.*), based on the photographs and their visual readout lists only 16 entries.  You find all of them in the subsequent re-investigation in 1983 ([here](http://rruff.geo.arizona.edu/AMS/xtal_data/DIFfiles/18036.txt), view text file *next to* download diffraction data), now with a total of observations equal to 37.

Thus, it is plausible the record card you accessed refers either to this set (1983) of data (or an  even more recent study) to list $(h,k,l)$ and their diffraction intensities, but credits Bannister for the first description of the very same phase in the 1930s.